# Is there a TShape control based on a TWinControl

Tags: delphi

Is there an equivalent control to TShape which will act as a container? I.e. derived from a WinControl

Comment: And why would you need that? Perhaps there are other solutions.

Comment: I exactly needed this one because sometimes you need to treat a shape at par with say buttons and edits. But the 'obj is TWinControl' check returns false for a TShape

Answer (score 2):

Not in the native VCL, no.  The closest would be a `TPanel` with a custom-painted background. Otherwise, you will have to write your own (or find a third-party one) that derives from `TCustomControl` or `TWinControl` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
unit WinShape_U;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls,
  Winapi.Windows, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Winapi.Messages;

type
  TWinShape = class(TWinControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FPen: TPen;
    FBrush: TBrush;
    FShape: TShapeType;
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
    procedure SetBrush(Value: TBrush);
    procedure SetPen(Value: TPen);
    procedure SetShape(Value: TShapeType);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    property Canvas: TCanvas read FCanvas;
    procedure ChangeScale(M, D: Integer; isDpiChange: Boolean); override;
    procedure Paint;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    procedure StyleChanged(Sender: TObject);
    property Align;
    property Anchors;
    property Brush: TBrush read FBrush write SetBrush;
    property DragCursor;
    property DragKind;
    property DragMode;
    property Enabled;
    property Constraints;
    property ParentShowHint;
    property Pen: TPen read FPen write SetPen;
    property Shape: TShapeType read FShape write SetShape default stRectangle;
    property ShowHint;
    property Touch;
    property Visible;
    property OnContextPopup;
    property OnDragDrop;
    property OnDragOver;
    property OnEndDock;
    property OnEndDrag;
    property OnMouseActivate;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseLeave;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnGesture;
    property OnStartDock;
    property OnStartDrag;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Additional', [TWinShape]);
end;

{ TShape }

procedure TWinShape.ChangeScale(M, D: Integer; isDpiChange: Boolean);
begin
  FPen.Width := MulDiv(FPen.Width, M, D);
  inherited;
end;

constructor TWinShape.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FCanvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
  TControlCanvas(FCanvas).Control := Self;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csReplicatable];
  Width := 65;
  Height := 65;
  FPen := TPen.Create;
  FPen.OnChange := StyleChanged;
  FBrush := TBrush.Create;
  FBrush.OnChange := StyleChanged;
end;

procedure TWinShape.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
   inherited CreateParams(Params);
   Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

destructor TWinShape.Destroy;
begin
  FPen.Free;
  FBrush.Free;
  FCanvas.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TWinShape.Paint;
var
  X, Y, W, H, S: Integer;
begin
  with Canvas do
  begin
    Pen := FPen;
    Brush := FBrush;
    X := Pen.Width div 2;
    Y := X;
    W := Width - Pen.Width + 1;
    H := Height - Pen.Width + 1;
    if Pen.Width = 0 then
    begin
      Dec(W);
      Dec(H);
    end;
    if W < H then S := W else S := H;
    if FShape in [stSquare, stRoundSquare, stCircle] then
    begin
      Inc(X, (W - S) div 2);
      Inc(Y, (H - S) div 2);
      W := S;
      H := S;
    end;
    case FShape of
      stRectangle, stSquare:
        Rectangle(X, Y, X + W, Y + H);
      stRoundRect, stRoundSquare:
        RoundRect(X, Y, X + W, Y + H, S div 4, S div 4);
      stCircle, stEllipse:
        Ellipse(X, Y, X + W, Y + H);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TWinShape.SetBrush(Value: TBrush);
begin
  FBrush.Assign(Value);
end;

procedure TWinShape.SetPen(Value: TPen);
begin
  FPen.Assign(Value);
end;

procedure TWinShape.SetShape(Value: TShapeType);
begin
  if FShape <> Value then
  begin
    FShape := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TWinShape.StyleChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TWinShape.WMEraseBkgnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
   Msg.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TWinShape.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  if not (csDestroying in ComponentState) then
  begin
    Canvas.Lock;
    try
      Paint;
    finally
      Canvas.Unlock;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```